# How to omit counting certain p tags within p tag counting function in wordpress

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, function

I need some help with my 2 WordPress function that I use inside my `functions.php` file to push ad codes within the blog article based on paragraph count.

**What code do you currently use?**

Here is the code that I currently using inside my `functions.php` file:

```
/*Add ad after 20 paragraph of post if there is more than 21 paragraph*/
add_filter( 'the_content', 'ad_20', 15 );

function ad_20( $content ) {
    global $post;
    if( check_paragraph_count_blog( $content ) > 21  ) {

        $ad_code = '...ad code goes here...';

        if ( $post->post_type == 'post' ) {
            return prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $ad_code, 20, $content );
        }


    } 
    return $content;

}

// Parent Function that makes the magic happen
function prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $insertion, $paragraph_id, $content ) {
    $closing_p = '</p>';
    $paragraphs = explode( $closing_p, $content );
    foreach ($paragraphs as $index => $paragraph) {

        if ( trim( $paragraph ) ) {
            $paragraphs[$index] .= $closing_p;
        }

        if ( $paragraph_id == $index + 1 ) {
            $paragraphs[$index] .= $insertion;
        }
    }

    return implode( '', $paragraphs );
}

//Check paragraph count on a blog post
function check_paragraph_count_blog( $content ) {
    global $post;
    if ( $post->post_type == 'post' ) {
        $count = substr_count( $content, '</p>' );
        return $count;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

**What's the problem with your code?**

Well, my code works fine without any error but it doesn't follow the full purpose that I want from this code.

**What do you want your code to do?**

The main problem with the code that I'm currently using and posted above is that both the `prefix_insert_after_paragraph()` function & `check_paragraph_count_blog()` function check for all `p` tags regardless of where they are located. But this is not what I want, I want the following:

- Don't consider the `p` tags present within `<code>`, `<pre>`, `<code class="some-language-name">`, `<pre class="some-language-name>`.
- Also don't consider `p` tags present within certain `div` tags, like for example `<div class="callout some-class some-other-class">`.

**What's the problem with those certain `div` tags?**

Well, I use several shortcode inside my article to show up some well designed note, callouts etc. Now if the counter consider those divs for counting then it may show up the ads within the shortcode design making the entire look and feel bad.

**Sample Paragraph Input**

```
<p>At the time of creating any blog or news based websites most webmasters gives the least amount of importance to the commenting system of their website, without even understanding the importance of it. Eventually comment section of a website is the only place where people interact with the author when they are exited or happy with the article and helps to grow the whole website community. In most cases they end up using some third party commenting system like Disqus or Spot.im etc. without even realizing what a blunder they are making. I’ve seen many websites (both big & popular as well as small websites) using Disqus commenting system, without even realizing the consequences. And by the time you will realize it, your site would have become so big & popular they you can’t take the risk of changing your commenting system. If you are thinking why, keep reading.</p>

<p><a href="I want to omit this P from counting"><img src="I want to omit this p from counting"></a></p>

<p>As creating websites has become very easy now-a-days many non-techy people can make a websites too, but they don’t get the insights of an experienced personal. Before writing this article I’ve used disqus for months to research it thoroughly and at the same time I’ve also tried Spot.im (a new player in this arena) but in both cases I’ve come up with the same conclusion. Never ever use these third party commenting system on your website. Here are the 7 facts about Disqus and similar commenting system for which I will suggest you to stay away from them.</p>
```

**What do you want from us?**

I need your help guys. It would be really helpful if someone can provide me a rewritten version of the `prefix_insert_after_paragraph()` and `check_paragraph_count_blog()` function which will do the `p` tag counting and checking by omitting the condition I've described above.

Thank you in advance, looking forward to your help.

---

**Some Update About the Answer Posted Below**

The answer posted below works just fine without any problem but **please note** that it can only be used once. For example if you want to push 3 ads within your blog post and hence created 3 functions like `ad_10()`, `ad_20()` and `ad_30()`, the below code will only work in any one of them. If you put it in more than 1 function within your WordPress `functions.php` you might get blank content. Something to keep in mind.

Comment: `return $content` is repeated code place it after `if` and also remove `else` in `ad_20()`;

Comment: Also, you can also initialize `$count` with 0 and remove `else` and after `if` return `$count` in `check_paragraph_count_blog()` ;

Comment: No remove `return $content;` from `if` in `ad_20()`;

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 there are 2 `if` there one of them returns `$content` just because the inside if doesn't gets true.

Comment: Just remove `return $content;` from the `if` in 'ad_20()' it's repeted;

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 got your point. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `DOMDocument` - and not regexes - you can easily handle the job. The idea is to selecting all `p` tags that are not within those specific elements or in other words all `p` tags that doesn't belong to such a parent.

It's all done by a XPath query:

```
//p[
    not(
        ancestor::div[contains(@class, 'callout') or contains(@class, 'callin')]
            or ancestor::pre
            or ancestor::code
            or a/img       # As per comments
        )
]
```

If you see you can find that it's a negated query which will look for all `p` elements which aren't a child of `div`s with `callout` or `callin` classes (you may add more classes following similar syntax), `pre` or `code` elements (Note: all `pre` and `code` elements)

By the way you don't need any other functions, all things are done in `ad_20()`

*Regexes are not a tool made for this kind of complex situations (HTML parsing). I don't say you can't parse HTML with that. You can but unless you know perfectly what you are doing.*

**[Live demo](https://3v4l.org/iUWj4)**

```
add_filter('the_content', 'ad_20', 15);
function ad_20($content) {

    global $post;

    $adCode = '...ad code goes here...';
    // Ad code will be added right after 20th paragraph
    $paragraphNumber = 20;
    // Convert to HTML entities
    $content = mb_convert_encoding($content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');

    if ($post->post_type == 'post') {
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        // Initializing a new DOM object
        $dom = new DOMDocument;
        // Load HTML content
        $dom->loadHTML($content, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
        // Initializing a new XPath object
        $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
        // Query all `p` tags that their parent is not those specific elements
        $paragraphs = $xpath->query('//p[not(ancestor::div[contains(@class, \'callout\') or contains(@class, \'callin\')] or ancestor::pre or ancestor::code or a/img)]');

        // If we have a number of satisfying paragraphs
        if ($paragraphs->length > $paragraphNumber) {
            // Loading and importing javascript code
            // <span> is important
            $script = '<span>.........code.........</span>';
            $newDom = new DOMDocument;
            $newDom->loadHTML($script, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
            $node = $newDom->getElementsByTagName('span')->item(0);
            $adNode = $dom->importNode($node, true);
            // Add our ad node after `$paragraphNumber`th paragraph
            $paragraphs->item($paragraphNumber)->parentNode->insertBefore($adNode, $paragraphs->item($paragraphNumber));
        }

        libxml_use_internal_errors(false); 
        return $dom->saveHTML();
    }

    return $content;
}
```

Comment: Yes also look at demo and please remove all your other comments to make it clean.

Comment: Yah just looked into it. The demo is working fine. Now I'm going to implement it on my actual site. Also please remove my ad code from the demo. These codes are confidential.